# How to encapsulate Model, Principal, HttpServletRequest into single object to be provided as method argument for all Spring MVC controller method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to avoid declaring/supplying same set of parameters to Spring MVC controller methods used throughout my application.
These are specific spring related parameters and not domain models/application objects.
These parameters include : 
`Device`, `Model`, `Principal`, `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`.

Is there a way to encapsulate all these into single object (or probably custom annotation) to supply these to all controller methods?

Comment: Encapsulate those parameters into a class and register a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to resolve the class as a method argument. Then use that class as a method argument. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html

Comment: I will definitely try this. But does this work for spring objects like Device, Principal etc? If yes how does spring inject these params in custom class?

Comment: Honestly im not sure